# Insert com lastInsertId() com erro

Tags: banco-de-dados, pdo

O código abaixo só insere na tabela pedido, já na produto_has_pedido não insere. Qual o erro ?

```
 public function criarPedido(){

        $consulta = 'INSERT into pedido(data, valorTotal, cliente_id) values(:data,:valorTotal,:clienteId)';

        $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($consulta);


        $stmt->bindParam(':data', $this->data);
        $stmt->bindParam(':valorTotal', $this->valorTotal);
        $stmt->bindParam(':clienteId', $this->clienteId);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo "Produto cadastrado.";


        /////////////////////////////////////// produto_has_pedido /////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $consulta2 = 'INSERT into produto_has_pedido(produto_id, pedido_id) values('.$this->produto_id.', '.$this->PDO->lastInsertId().')';

        $stmt2 = $this->PDO->prepare($consulta2);




        $stmt2->execute();


}
```

Comment: Publique também qual a msg de erro exibida e qual a linha! Assim fica mais fácil te ajudar!

Comment: O problema é esse, não aparece erro, ele simplesmente não insere na tabela produto_has_pedido

Comment: Tente utilizar `print_r($this->PDO->errorInfo());` para avaliar o erro!

Comment: quais sao os campos da tabela, pk, fk? quais valores vc esta tentando inserir? nao seria um problema de pk duplicada?  vc confiriu esses valores '.$this->produto_id.', '.$this->PDO->lastInsertId().' pq pode ser null...

Comment: foreign key é pedido_id

Comment: da um echo nesses valores '.$this->produto_id.', '.$this->PDO->lastInsertId().' para saber se nao sao vazios

Comment: Ele retorna corretamente o id do produto e o ultimo id do pedido